# Using .match and the difference between .search

Tags: javascript

I used the following code for coderbyte:

```
function VowelCount(str) {
    // code goes here  
    return str.match(/[aeiou]/gi).length;
}

// keep this function call here
// to see how to enter arguments in JavaScript scroll down
print(VowelCount(readline()));
```

I understand most of the code, except for the following parts:

1. What do the forward slashes and the square brackets do?
2. What does the `gi` do?
3. What is the difference between `search()` and `match()`? What condition should I use what in?

Comment: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp and https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Quoting [the doc](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/search):

> When you want to know whether a pattern is found in a string use
>   `search` (similar to the regular expression `test` method); for more
>   information (but slower execution) use `match` (similar to the regular
>   expression `exec` method).

In this case, it's not enough just to know that a vowel (either 'a', 'e', 'i', 'o', or 'u' - that's what's expressed with so-called character class expression, `[aeiou]`) is in the string, as the purpose of the function is to *count* vowels.

So it scans the string, collecting *all* (that's what `/g` modifier is for) the matches, regardless of character case (`/i`), into an array, then returns the length of this array.

There's a bug in this function, however. As [String.match](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match) returns `null` if no matches were found, the function throws an error if param string has no vowels at all:

```
VowelCount('ddd'); // TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of null
```

It has to be fixed with additional check for the match result.

```
function vowelCount(str) {
  var vowels = str.match(/[aeiou]/gi);
  return vowels ? vowels.length : 0;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The slashes delimit a regular expression (`RegExp()`)  literal (as opposed to using `new RegExp()` notation), the square brackets are a series of characters for the regular expression to match.

References:

- [`RegExp()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/RegExp).

Answer (score 0):

forward slashes wraps regular expression statement.

**gi** means search will be global (all occurances) and case insensitive.

Answer (score 0):

There's several functions to search for a string in another string, the probably most famous ones being `.indexOf()`, `.search()`, `.match()`.

```
str.indexOf(s)
```

Returns index (position) of ***first*** matching String **s inside** string **str**.

```
str.search(s)
```

Does *what indexOf() does* but **allows** s to be not just a string but a **regular expression**. (Actually, it even sees a 'normal' string as such).

```
str.match(s)
```

Is like *search() but* instead of returning the first occurence's index, it **returns *all* occurence's as an array**.

---

Now, regarding the

> /[]/

and similar, this is (an example of) a before mentioned regular expression. More info on what does what can be found [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions/Cheatsheet). In short, it defines a string pattern to search for and how to search for it.

Comment: `str.match(s)` will not return _all_ occurences. This happens if `/g` is provided; otherwise, only the first complete match and its related capturing groups are returned. More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/match